# Posting email adress from flash to mysql using as3 and php

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

im trying to send a name and email address from flash to an sql server, but i can't seem to get it working.

Heres the code.

```
 import flash.events.Event;

 stop();

    submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendData);
    function sendData(evt:MouseEvent){

        //if(email.text!="" && nameval.text !=""){
            var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest("animation.php")
            myData.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables()
            variables.emailpost = "test";
            // email.text
            variables.namepost = "test";
            //nameval.text
            myData.data = variables
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT
            loader.load(myData)
            play();

  //} 

    }
```

And here's the PHP

```
<?php
  //Capture data from $_POST array
  $emailpost = $_POST['emailpost'];
  $namepost= $_POST['namepost'];
  //Connection to database
  $connect = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
  mysql_select_db ("dbname", $connect);
  //Perform the query
      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbname VALUES('$emailpost', '$namepost')");
      mysql_close($connect);



?>
```

I've took most of this code from other websites so its cut and i'm not 100% sure whats missing from it to cause it to work.

Also does it matter that the database is on a different server to the php file and animation?

Comment: Try using an absolute URL: `var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://example.com/animation.php")`

Comment: That didn't change anything :/ Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Do you see the data being posted? (with some request analyzer, e.g. httpFox in Firefox)

Comment: Just checked, seems to be posting fine, so the php script must be the problem.

Comment: Isn't it a security related issue then? Btw, if you don't need to wait for response (as you are not receiving any in your code), there is no need to use URLLoader. sendToURL() would be absolutely sufficient.